# For loop over subsetted pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, indexing

I am trying to iteratively create subsets of a dataframe. A toy example:

```
In:

   A  B  participant  
0  1  3            1          
1  2  4            1         
2  5  8            2          
3  4  9            2
4  3  7            3
```

(The conditional statement thanks to the commenter below)

```
for p in df:
    subset = df[df['participant'] == p].loc[: , 'A']
```

The desired outcome is:

```
   A  participant  
0  1            1          
1  2            1

   A  participant  
0  5            2          
1  4            2
```

etc.

But the for loop makes a subset by row, not by participant. How to get subsets per participant?

original attempt:

```
for p in df:
    p.pressure = df[(:, 'pressure') & (df['participant'] == p)]
```

Comment: Ok, thank you but it looks like now I'm looping over column titles instead of speakers now?

Comment: You _could_ change it to `for p in df['participant']` but I feel like this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it that you're trying to do? There's likely an easier solution, maybe using `groupby()`.

Comment: I want to know how to iteratively subset over a dataframe using the same criteria each time. In this example, the for loop should give subsets of all the pressure values for each participant. Current syntax gives duplicate subsets.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example with sample inputs and desired outputs? Try to provide a [mcve]. More on [how to create good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: question edited with toy dataframe above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way.

First get the unique values for participants:

```
participants = df['participant'].unique()
#array([1, 2, 3])
```

Now create a dataframe for each participant. In this example, I will store each DF in a dictionary, keyed by the participant number.

```
output_dfs = {p: df[df['participant'] == p] for p in participants}
for p in output_dfs:
    print("Participant = %s"%p)
    print(output_dfs[p])
    print("")
```

Which prints:

```
Participant = 1
   A  B  participant
0  1  3            1
1  2  4            1

Participant = 2
   A  B  participant
2  5  8            2
3  4  9            2

Participant = 3
   A  B  participant
4  3  7            3
```